# Lotteries, Turan's problem, and minimization of risk

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, combinatorial-optimization

Suppose I am a high-volume broker aiming to make some money on a state lottery.  In this lottery, six balls are drawn from a population of (let's say) 50, without replacement.  A ticket is a choice of a size-6 subset of 1,2,..50.

The prize structure of this lottery is such that the jackpot alone doesn't impart much value to the ticket.  But it turns out that lesser prizes are sufficiently large relative to their probability that the ticket has a positive expected value, which is why I'm buying a lot of tickets in the first place.  For instance, I can expect to get a pretty substantial return from tickets which match 4 of the 6 numbers drawn by the lottery.

There is a substantial literature related to the "Turan problem," which asks:  what is the minimum number of tickets I need to purchase in order to *guarantee* that one of my tickets matches 4 of the 6 numbers in the lottery?

My question is somewhat different.  Let's say I have enough capital to buy a fixed number N of tickets, large in absolute terms but small relative to 50 choose 6.  Then my expected gain is fixed.  But of course as a wise investor I may want to minimize the variance of my winnings.

Thus my question.

*If the random variable X is the number of (4 out of 6) wins among my N tickets, how small can I make Var(X) by judicious choice of ticket purchases?*

(Of course, the same question applies for (k out of 6) where k=2,3,5.)

By the way, in case the setup seems unrealistic, let me add that the reason I'm asking this is that the situation described here *actually happened*, and I'm trying to reverse-engineer what the broker's risk-minimization strategy must have been, and assess whether it was worth it.

Comment: I am not a professional, so please consult one to fix any mistakes below.  A BIBD will often have subsets of a set of size v with b many such (blocks), often all of size t (for treatment, don't ask me why) with a parameter lambda so that every pair of elements from the v set is covered by exactly lambda many blocks.  To minimize variance, you want a design (which exist in the literature) with pair replaced by quadruple and with as close as possible to having a lambda.  Partial designs exist, and the La Jolla Repository might help.  Gerhard "Ask Me Not About Combinatorics" Paseman, 2012.10.26

Comment: Every lottery situation I have seen with tickets of positive expected value has come from the jackpot. Are you sure the smaller prizes were large enough? Also, how large is the number of tickets you buy compared with the total number of combinations?

Comment: I'm sure.  The folks in question bought about 200,000 tickets per drawing and ended up making on the order of $3.5m over the life of the enterprise, never winning a jackpot.

Comment: Do you have a link with more details about what happened?

Comment: http://www.mass.gov/ig/publications/reports-and-recommendations/2012/lottery-cash-winfall-letter-july-2012.pdf

Comment: Very interesting. The Inspector General's conclusion that ordinary bettors were not disadvantaged by the high volume groups is obviously wrong. 

Comment: @Douglas Zare: IMO this is an unfair summary of the text. For some (in the given context) reasonable interpretations of "disadvantaged by the high volume groups" it seems true. 

Comment: Yeah, Douglas, I'm with the Inspector General here!  (I'm trying to get in touch with him to clarify some details, no luck yet, but let me know if you have any questions for him...)

Comment: @Douglas: the ordinary bettors were hurt only in the same sense as me bidding in an auction hurting someone else chance of winning.

Comment: I don't think it's an unfair summary. On page 25, the IG concluded "As long as the Lottery announced to the public an impending $2 million jackpot that would likely trigger a roll-down, an ordinary bettor buying a single ticket or any number of tickets was not disadvantaged by high-volume betting. In short, no one’s odds of having a winning ticket were affected by high-volume betting." The second sentence is supposed to reinforce the first, no? The IG is saying there was no problem, no? But *the amount of the payoffs per win* to the other players was significantly reduced...

Comment: ... and this is shown by the sharp decline in the amounts of the prizes as the high volume groups soaked up most of the profits. From page 12, "By 2007, the Lottery sold between 1.2 million and 1.4 million tickets for nearly every roll-down drawing, with Dr. Zhang and other high-volume bettors making the bulk of the wagers. At that point, the payouts on roll-downs were split among a larger number of winning tickets. As a result, the payouts dropped to about one-third the size they had been..." How can you not count getting paid $1/3$ as much as being disadvantaged?

Comment: By the way, there is an easy way to read off the variance from the pairwise Hamming distances, since the second moment is the expected square of a sum of indicators, and the probability that two indicators are both $1$ only depends on the size of the intersections of those tickets. 

Comment: In games with negative expected winnings, one clearly wants to have relatively high variance (otherwise, one surely lose).
You want to have a very small variance, and this is archived when playing many games (optimal strategy in games with expected loss, is to play as few games as possible). Thus, buy only one ticket at a time (and winnings can then be used to buy more tickets), until you can buy enough to guarantee win. 

Comment: @Douglas Zare: yes, sure. For some *other* reasonable interpretations of "being disadvantaged by the high-volume groups" there obviously was a disadvanatage. My point is: in these roll-down rounds each and every (additional) bet disadvantaged the others. Yet, there seems to be no disadvantage being *specific to* the fact that many bets coming from one entity. Or, to put it conversely, the high-volume groups had no advanatage over the rest (beyond smaller variance) *due to* being high-volume. Whether 1 buys 100000 or 1000 buy 100 each or 100000 buy 1 each, this all has the same effect...       

Comment: ...So, IMO, the answer depends really on the definition of "being disadvantaged by the high-volume groups". There is none made explicit. But for example you quote "In short, no one’s odds of having a winning ticket were affected by high-volume betting." This seems completely true. One can say it is an oversimplification to focus on this, or even it is besides the point. But it is *not* wrong. Yet whether this is besides the point or not depends on the context. I do not know it. But at the start there is also discussion whether these groups had some connections to the lottery and so on...   

Comment: ...suggesting to me that the main point of this report was to find out whether there was some activity that was outside the rules of the lottery. And to this the answer that is given essentially (there is some discussion on placing bets outside regular hours and so on) is: no these groups played according to the rules, and everbody could have made the same thing, and if many individuals independently would have bought more bets this would have had the same effect. Or, the high-volume groups are not different from the collection of many small volume groups. *Thus,* there was no reason to...    

Comment: ...do anything against them in order to protect regular participants. Now, for the lottery itself it might not have been so good that the advertisment effect of these roll-down rounds is a bit degraded by these high-volume groups, but this then is still something else. And after all eventually it seems they stopped this type of game. Or, still differently, the regular participants played the game the thought to play, and were not betrayed in any way. Sure, the game could have been more advantageous for them under other circumstances. But, then for each individual... 

Comment: ...the best would be if only they could play in the roll-down. But, well, this clearly is a non option and they always will be disadvanated by all the others high-volume or not. Thus I maintain my opinion that this is (for the context I believe it was made) a reasonable conclusion. [There is one exception, but this is also treated separately and described as a problem. Namely, when one group triggered an unexpected roll-down. Here and only here, I would say there was some  disadvantge by high-volume groups, or at least undue advantage for one high-volume group.]

Comment: Let me put it another way. If you bought one ticket per drawing in 2005, before the high volume groups moved in, what was your expected return? For the sake of argument, let's say $60$ cents on the dollar. How about if you did that in 2008 when high volume groups absorbed most of the rollovers? Perhaps something like $30$ cents on the dollar. I would call that a disadvantage. I look forward to another page of comments explaining how the amount somehow doesn't matter.

Comment: By the way, if you just bought $700,000 worth of tickets, too, I think that would push the expected profits negative for everyone. 

Comment: @Douglas Zare: perhaps you missed my first sentence 'yes, sure. For some other reasonable interpretations of "being disadvantaged by the high-volume groups" there obviously was a disadvanatage.' Not sure why you think there is a need for repeating. (I think your BTW was also pointed out in the report; perhaps it was not that bad after all ;D)

Comment: Does anyone other than the Inspector General think this agrees with the common definition of "not disadvantaged?" Sure, you can say someone is not disadvantaged if their pay is cut by a factor of $3$ because their pay checks are just as frequent as before, but this does not agree with the normal definitions of those words.

Comment: @Dougals Zare: there are a couple of things. First, many things in mathematics, say, do not agree with the "normal definition of those words" either. This does not make it meaningless or wrong. One just has to know the meaning *in that specific context*. This is not so unlike in law (sometimes and roughly speaking), which is my main point all along. To really judge the report one would have to know what precisely was even asked for, not assume some common sense interpretation of some phrase as the right one, and rush to judgement. Second, it says "disadvantaged by the high-volume gps"

Comment: Now, in my opinion the way to understand this is was there any disadvanatage that was *specific* to the fact that there existed "high-volume groups." As opposed to was there any disagvantage due to the higher volume (that happened to be create by a only few individuals but could theoretically have been created otherwise too). To me this is not the same, and it seems conceivable that the former question was the one to be answered in this report. Because, if the type of disadvanatge you point out was to be avoided, 

Comment: say also ads for this lottery would need to be avoided as they will increase the volume and make the game less advantageous for those that would have played regardless. And, to answer the question you want to answer there would really be no need for a report. This type of disadvanatge is obvious having the definition of the game at hand whenever anybody in addition plays.     

Comment: Ok, you propose that according to some legal definitions, the Inspector General was not wrong. I would like to see your source for those definitions. In the ordinary use of those English words, the conclusion was obviously wrong.

Comment: @Douglas Zare: I did not propose he was not wrong, I propose he might not be wrong. I do not have a source, and I never claimed having one. I said  for example "one would have to know what precisely was even asked for". I do not know, but you know neither (I assume). So you cannot say it is wrong. You took *one* (naive) reading and claim it is the *only* sensible one. Well, if you want to insist on this, fine. I think I explained in sufficient detail why I personally consider other readings as in principle reasonable, too, and indeed more likely to be those relevant in the given context... 

Comment: ...since you seem not interested in trying to understand what I am trying to say or even to point out short-comings in my line of argument, further discussion seems not productive. If you would like to continue I would be interested in you explaining why to make the distincition I pointed out 'disad by higher-volume, generally' and 'disad specific to higher-volume created by only few individuals' is not relevant. And/or if you see any that falls into the second category *only*. I mean if one cannot establish something in the 2nd cat, one might have had a hard time banning it.   

Comment: To put it still differently: 'disadvantaged by the higher volume' and 'disadvanatged by the high-volume groups' to me are two quite different things; by contrast for you it seems to be the same.  

Answer (score 4):

This is not a real "answer" but an observation. Each 6-tuple has ${6 \choose 4}$ 4-tuples, so it stands to reason that once $N$ is some smallish multiple $m$ of ${50\choose 4}/{6\choose 4}$ then Bob's your uncle, and you can come reasonably close to equidistribution. This is to be contrasted with (say) the binomial expectation. The number of fours (or more) you expect is ${6\choose 4}m$, and the reasonable size $N=138180$ gives $m=9$ and 135 fours. The binomial distribution gives a variance about of slightly under $135$. I expect that one can essentially ensure about 135, plus or minus a small amount, via some covering selection.

ADDITION: In verities, the binomial model does not well model the random choices, as they have considerably higher variance, 180-185 compared to 134.8. I do not understand the theoretical concepts *in toto*, but an aspect is that the coverage of fours from the random sixes is already askew.

UPDATE: OK, here's the skinny on covering. I did a rather simple process. Do the following 138180 times. Pick a 4-tuple that so far has not appeared 9 times. Append to it the 2 numbers for which the resulting six minimizes the sum of the current counts of its 15 sub-fours. Accumulate the counts of 4-tuples from this six.

Then apply a bit of post-processing if you want (throw out populous sixes). This gives a set of 138180 6-tuples in which every 4-tuple appears between 7 and 11 times (the average is 135/15 or 9, with random choices of sixes the four-counts will range from 0 to 20 or more). Then simulate the ${50\choose 6}$ lotteries. These give an expectation of 135 fours, the minimum was 120 and the maximum was 149. The variance was a mere 5.8, versus 135 (binomial) or 180 (random). The binomial distro gives less than 120 a 8.9% chance (and more than 149 a 10.7% chance). As added above, the actual random distro is even worse than binomial.

I think this shows that with a (small) bit of work, some quite good variance reduction is possible. You can try to further trim the ends if desired. In the actual example, their edge was about 20-25% when free bets were included (later comments suggest 15-20% over the history). The accounting on page 7 says "12.8%" for just the cash component, but I get 425840/400000 is 6.4%. This analysis also lacks the jackpot, which I guess is equally likely to help/hurt among the big players (it is slightly chancey that only 1 of the 45 jackpots was hit, given there are 2-4 groups each buying up to 1/30 of the pool every time).

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/3tygt.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/3tygt.jpg)

Comment: I think you mean standard devation around sqrt(135)?  But the point stands -- even picking things randomly gives you a level of risk which , compared with most investments with mildly positive expected value, is pretty good.  I still wonder about how well one can do with a covering, though!

Comment: This is awesome!  But I too am confused about why the random model is not giving you something that looks like binomial.

Comment: Part of it maybe the 5s and 6s effect. In that random sample, the max is 222, in there are 9 fives and 1 six, giving an "extra" four count of 36+14 above independence. The import of duplicates in the 138180 is similar, as a twofer guarantees an extra 28 non-independent for some lottery occurrence. Triplicates are likely too (80% chance).